# React and Redux : Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch,

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux to update the state of one item. but getting error

**Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: rootReducer.cartReducer.carts.0.qnty**. Take a look at the reducer(s)

Here is the reducer code :

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  carts: [],
};

export const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CART":
    /*   return {
        ...state,
        carts: [...state.carts, action.payload],
      }; */
      const IteamIndex = state.carts.findIndex((iteam)=> iteam.id === action.payload.id);
      if(IteamIndex >= 0){
          state.carts[IteamIndex].qnty +=1
          return {
              ...state,
              carts:[...state.carts]
          }
      }else{
          const temp = {...action.payload,qnty:1}
           return {
              ...state,
              carts: [...state.carts, temp]
          }
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I tried assign state to a new varriable and do the changes into it and pass the variable but no luck

```
export const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CART":
    /*   return {
        ...state,
        carts: [...state.carts, action.payload],
      }; */
      let newState={...state}
      const IteamIndex = newState.carts.findIndex((iteam)=> iteam.id === action.payload.id);
      if(IteamIndex >= 0){
          newState.carts[IteamIndex].qnty +=1
          return {
              ...newState,
              carts:[...newState.carts]
          }
      }else{
          const temp = {...action.payload,qnty:1}
           return {
              ...state,
              carts: [...state.carts, temp]
          }
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating `state.carts[IteamIndex]`, `state.carts[IteamIndex].qnty += 1` is the state mutation. In legacy Redux reducers you need to apply the [Immutable Update Pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), e.g. all state, ***and nested state***, necessarily should be shallow copied ***then*** updated.

Example:

```js
export const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CART":
      const iteamIndex = state.carts.findIndex((iteam) => iteam.id === action.payload.id);
      if (iteamIndex >= 0) {
        return {
          ...state,
          carts: state.carts.map((iteam, index) => { // <-- shallow copy cart array
            if (iteamIndex === index) {
              return {               // <-- new iteam object
                ...iteam,            // <-- shallow copy iteam
                qnty: iteam.qnty + 1 // <-- update quantity
              };
            }
            return iteam;
          }),
        }
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          carts: [...state.carts, {...action.payload, qnty: 1 }],
        }
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```